# Start a new page and avoid blank page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

I want my `\section` is always in a new page, so I need a `\newpage` before `\section`.

What about the current page is new page already? How do I avoid it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: two `\newpage` will not make two page breaks: a `\newpage` at  top of the page is ignored, but it is better to define `\section` to include the page break (as `\chapter` is normally defined) rather than putting `\newpage` before each section by hand

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? Prepending the `\section` code with a `\clearpage` should do.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpretocmd{\section}{\clearpage}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\blindtext[5]

\section{Second}
\blindtext[20]

\section{Gandalf}
\blindtext[10]


\end{document}
```

Comment: I bet this will closed as a dupe, you could answer the other question. ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B: If it's closed... I don't care. Which other question?

Comment: the possible dupe @werner marked above. I prefer your answer over the accepted `titlesec` one

Comment: @Johannes_B: Nope, I won't add an answer to a question from the Stone Age :-D